# How to create a pop up Window but not lose the previous Window

Tags: javascript, titanium, appcelerator

I created a new small window to open with Onlick Function. How can i keep the previous window when the new pop up opens? Now i got a black background outside of my pop up.

XML

```
<Alloy>
 <Window id="container" backgroundImage="/images/art.jpg">
    <View id="weSocial" width="95%" top="8" backgroundColor="#393939" height="50" visible="true" onClick="showSocial">
      <Label id="socialLabel"></Label>
     </View>
   </Window>
 </Alloy>
```

JS:

```
var ModalWindow = Ti.UI.createWindow({
        title: L('findSocial'),
        backgroundColor: "red",
        width: "300",
        height: "300",
        modal: true,
        top: "10%"
    });
$.win.add.ModalWindow;

function showSocial () {
    ModalWindow.open({modal:true}); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're thinking of a view. A window within iOS (and also Android if I'm not mistaken) is always 100% wide & high.

Even though you made your view 95%, the window isn't. The reason it is black, is because your window has a black background.

To change this, instead of opening a new window, simply add (and overlay) the view to your current window.

Your new XML:

```
<Alloy>
    <View id="weSocial" width="95%" top="8" backgroundColor="#393939" height="50" visible="true" onClick="showSocial">
      <Label id="socialLabel"></Label>
     </View>
 </Alloy>
```

Include it in your previous window through the controller:

```
var controller = Alloy.createController('modalWindow');
```

Add and show it:

```
$.getView().add(controller.getView());
```

Your tss for the `modalWindow` should still be 95% wide, and don't position it using left and right, and it will center automatically.